# Reading and then working on stream data

Tags: c++, stream

I'm working on a problem 4-6 from Accelerated C++.  The question asks that I rewrite the `Student_info` struct, `read()` function, and `grade()` function, so that the final grade is calculated immediately and then stored as the only grade in `Student_info`.

Previously, the program worked as follows:

1. `read()` reads from an input stream and stores the data into a `Student_info` object
2. Each object is added to a vector
3. Once every object is read and added, `grade()` is called on every `Student_info` object in the vector

With the new constraints I feel I must combine the `read()` and `grade()` functions, so there is no need to store intermediate grades.  The problem is when reading from the stream I don't know I have run into the end of file, until I do.  When doing this I try to call the `grade()` function on the end of file data.

I don't see a workaround considering the constraint is to read and then immediately work on the data. How can this be handled?

```
struct Student_info 
{
    std::string name;
    double final_grade;
};

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
    double midterm, final;
    is >> s.name >> midterm >> final;

    // Error, when EOF is read, grade() will process bad data
    s.final_grade = grade(midterm, final);
    return is;
}

void main()
{
    vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    while (read(cin, record))
        students.push_back(record);
}
```

Comment: Please show the current code; it will be easier to understand than your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the record was successfully read inside the `read` function. For example like this:

```
istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
    string name;
    double midterm, final;

    if( is >> name >> midterm >> final ) {
        s.name = name;
        s.final_grade = grade(midterm, final);
    }

    return is;
}
```

Note that you *could* read directly into `s.name` as in your original code, but my implementation has transaction semantics: it either reads the whole structure or leaves it alone in case it failed to read all the fields.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have transaction semantics with respect to the stream, but I'm unsure on how to do that in a clean way.